# Deserializing array of objects, edit, then serialize again

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have to following scenario:

1. Deserializing an array of (unknown) objects like: `[{ a: 5, b: 2}, { a: 2, b: 7}, ...]`
2. (Doing stuff with the data)
3. Serialize the data and output it as json

Now if I deserialze the data, using `JArray.Parse` etc.

When I now serialize this data again, the properties of the objects (a, b) are stored as key/value pairs like this: `{ key: "a", value: 5 }` and so on.

How do I deserialize the data so that it is saved as an object with properties and values, and not as some sort of a collection of dictionaries?

**Edit**: for serialization, I use `return Json(new { data = deserializedData })`. It is of course done in a Asp.net MVC 5 controller.

Comment: How are you serialising the data?

Comment: Just realized I should mention this, see edit & thanks!